# Android OpenGL ES Multiple Textures for one rect

Tags: android, opengl-es

In Android OpenGL ES, I want to be able to switch textures for a given Rectangle. I have one rect and I put two textures, depending on different conditions. I just want to switch between textures.

I followed this code to create the textures:
[link text](http://blog.poweredbytoast.com/loading-opengl-textures-in-android)

and they render fine, but then I don't know how to tell the given rect to use another texture. Do I do something like "setTexture" with the ID that is generated in loadTextures() ? Do I have to have an array with texture names (numbers) that I then change .. I just don't get it..

Answer (score 1):

[`glBindTexture()`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glBindTexture.xml).

Comment: Yes I know about that, the problematic part is the second argument of that function, do I put the ID generated by (in my case) newTextureID() method or do I put something else? :/ I manage to get working objects with textures on them, the problem comes when I want to change one of those textures.

Comment: @Adolf: Yep, just toss in those IDs.  They're just ints, so keep them in an array somewhere if you want.